# Use replace() function in an update to change more than one sub string of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, pattern-matching

Say I have `student` table with a column `name`.
This `name` column has values 'studentone', 'studenttwo', 'studentthree'
& I want to replace them with 'student1', 'student2', 'student3'.

For single replacement it's quite straight forward:

```
update student set name = replace(name, 'one', '1')
```

But what about multiple replacements? Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just use multiple update statements, but if you absolutely must do it in one statement, just nest the replace calls:

```
update student set
  name = replace(replace(replace(name, 'one', '1'), 'two', '2'), 'three', '3')
```

This works because (although inefficient) calls to `replace()` have no effect if the search term is not found.

Comment: yup that works but multiple update statements seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 3):

While you *could* pack all into one statement, it would be inefficient without a matching **`WHERE` condition** to exclude unaffected rows.

```
UPDATE student SET name = replace(name, 'one', '1') WHERE name LIKE '%one';
UPDATE student SET name = replace(name, 'two', '2') WHERE name LIKE '%two';
UPDATE student SET name = replace(name, 'three', '3') WHERE name LIKE '%three';
```

This only finds and updates rows that actually change. Matching the end of the string according to your example.
The most efficient way would be to combine that with something [like @Bohemian suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727784/939860):

```sql
UPDATE student
SET    name = replace(replace(replace(
                      name
                    , 'one'  , '1')
                    , 'two'  , '2')
                    , 'three', '3')
WHERE name ~ '(one|two|three)$';
```

But make sure that one replacement does not influence the next.

Actually, a couple of OR'ed `LIKE` expressions are typically faster than a single [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), so:

```
WHERE (name LIKE '%one' OR
       name LIKE '%two' OR
       name LIKE '%three');
```

#### `CASE`

Per comment:

```sql
SET    name = CASE WHEN name LIKE '%one' THEN replace(name, 'one', '1')
                   WHEN name LIKE '%two' THEN replace(name, 'two', '2')
                   WHEN name LIKE '%three' THEN replace(name, 'three', '3')
              END
```

Depending on *exact* circumstances, this might be optimized. For your example:

```sql
SET    name = CASE right(name, -7)
                 WHEN 'one'   THEN student || '1'
                 WHEN 'two'   THEN student || '2'
                 WHEN 'three' THEN student || '3'
              END
```

Requires above `WHERE` clause to work properly.

Comment: hmmm... right. I thought something could be done using CASE WHEN THEN  in 1 update statement.

Comment: @user1298426: `CASE` is possible, too - and might be the better choice if earlier replacements could otherwise influence later replacements, which is not the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prebuilt function here for replacing multiple strings in one go, using a JSON dictionary format for the input, e.g.:

```
select multi_replace('foo and bar is not foobar',
             '{"bar":"foo", "foo":"bar", "foobar":"foobar"}'::jsonb);
```

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Multi_Replace_plpgsql

Comment: I cant understand why this function uses regex functions inside. Looping through jsonb_each_text and using replace on every key|value runs so much faster, especially on large texts.